# Center WooCommerce archives page and single product pages

Tags: html, css, woocommerce, product

The store page of my website is made using woocommerce.php file, the store page itself is fine, but I would just like to center the products.

Is there a way to do this?

Also, within the single product view when clicking from the store page the image and description of the product is huge and not correctly positioned.

Is there a way to style single product images and descriptions?

Here is [the live link](http://rewindrecordings.co.uk/shop/) to my web site.

Comment: http://rewindrecordings.co.uk/shop/ this is the page, the only issue im having now is that there seems to be an invisible sidebar pushing the products to the left?

Comment: You are required to post your markup that shows the problem here within your question and not your web site which will change as soon as this is solved and help no one in the future. [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose between that 2 ways:

**1) CSS way** — You should need to add this CSS rule to the styles.css file of your active theme:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .woocommerce center > .col-md-10 {
        margin: 0 8.33333333% !important;
    }
}
```

This should solve your centering issue on all WooCommerce pages

---

**2) HTML structure way** — This problem can be solved in your **html structure**.

Actually you got this:

```
<div id="primary" class="col-md-12 mb-xs-24">
    <center>
        <div class="col-md-10">
```

You should need to have this instead:

```
<div id="primary" class="col-md-12 mb-xs-24">
    <div class="col-md-12">
```

This will make the display at 100% inside the container instead of 83% to the left.

> As [**Rob**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162698/rob) suggested in the comments you should remove obsolete `<center>` html tag…

Comment: Do not answer off topic questions that do not provide the required markup within their question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: The `<center>` tag has been obsolete for years. Do not use that tag.